# prevent a user from writing data to firestore if data exist

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

I am making an android app that when a user register an account on firebase, he saves his email, phone number and password. but when he wants to login, he uses his phone number and password. Because of that requirement I must also make the phone number unique There are a number of ways too do this but my options are limited because the database is already being used by a working system and me making changes to it will cause the other system not to work. The best way to solve my problem without affecting the other system is by modifying the rules to prevent a user from adding an phone number that already exist.

My database structure is like this

```
    users {
        userID {
             name: "John"
             phone: "2342222"
             address: "23rd Avenue"
             email: "email@mail.com"
        }userID 2 {
             name: "Mark"
             phone: "2342222"
             address: "5th Avenue"
             email: "email@mail.com"
        }
   }
```

Now my rules look like this

```
    service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
     match /Users/{anything=**}  {   
      allow write: if auth != null && !data.exists() && data == request.auth.uid;
    }match /Users/{userId}  {   
      allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId;


// I need a rule maybe here that will allow me write phone number to the database
// If the number doesn't exist in my entire Users database.

    }match /user-compare/{anything=**} {   
    allow read: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Ive tried

```
allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId && !request.resource.data.phone in resource.data.phone;
```

I want to make sure that a user can only read and write data inside its user ID, but my rules should be the one to prevent duplicate data not the source codes because due to the way the other system is setup, if multiple users have the same phone number, it will crash, and right now my app is the only way to make multiple users with the same phone number.

I know I can create a new collection to holder the numbers and then check if the number exist there for the registration process, but if anyone uses the other system to register, the numbers will not appear in this new collection.

The best way is if I can write a rule. My problem is a bit different from what I've seen and I hope I'm explaining properly. any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You should use Firebase Authentication since that provides the functionality of unique Mobile number signin. Along with that you should also save that mobile number as well as email and other user information if the sign in is successful.

Comment: Yes, That was what was being used but the way the Firebase SDK is set up, I cant really do much with the information stored in Authentication unless I install the admin sdk but I didn't want to use that so it was best to avoid that since I wasn't able to edit the information that I would be saving there easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't solve it with rules no matter what I tried but Using Firebase Admin SDK will allow a developer write/edit/view information in Authentication section of the Service and this will allow you make the changes and validate them. You can learn more [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup). This can be added as a  dependency on the app but Due to the nature of the service I didn't feel that It'll be safe giving users access to an app with admin privileges. But this is a solution when you have the application for example in the office and users only have access to it in a save environment and can be used to add more functionality for staffs or authorized member's use.

For me, what solved my security concerns was to install the Admin SDK on a server. For my problem this can be used in two ways. I can make a custom authentication found [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth) and use that to sign in users using their phone number and password. But what I chose to do was make a simple API to take the phone number and check if there's any email address associated with it. if Yes retrieve the email and use that together with the password and sign in with email and password. so basically it uses the usual email and password sign in, but the user input their number and password instead. This was what worked for me and I hope it helped someone in a similar position.